# Unable to add new fragment inside BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

I am trying to add a new fragment from inside BottomSheetDialogFragment. Below is code snippet:

Adding a BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
FragmentA.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentA.TAG);
```

Adding new fragment inside FragmentA

```
 getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(FragmentB.newInstance(), FragmentB.TAG).commit();
```

I checked the logs and it looks like, FragmentB is getting added in stack but not visible to user.

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: can you please add more code?

Comment: why do you need to add the child fragment to the bottom sheet fragment? what do you try to accomplish? I usually start fragments via parent activity and supportFragmentManager

Comment: I better if you show code that relate to your BottomSheetDialogFragment, and the stack trace when you add a new fragment in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hide your first fragment. You can check with below code:-

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragmentB, "B").hide(fragmentB).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragmentA, "A").commit();
```

On Navigation Selection, You can use below code:-

```
fm.beginTransaction().hide(FragmentA).show(FragmentB).commit();
```